# Kibana Returns 200 Code But Browser Shows Not Ready

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I have an Electron application that uses Kibana iframes in it. I am using a splash screen to wait for Kibana before showing my program interface, so that user will not see the "Kibana server not ready yet" text. I am trying to send GET request to "http://localhost:5601/status" to check if it returns 200 as status code. Doing this in a loop until I get 200 response and when I got the 200 code I close splash screen and show my program interface. However Kibana iframes still shows Kibana server not ready yet error. What is the reason behind this? Is there any other API URL that I can check to determine Kibana is completely ready? Please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no `200` in the response. I think you are looking at whether the call to `http://localhost:5601/status` was successful which returns a 200. which means Kibana is up but probalbly not ready yet or is "warming up"

[image: API status]

However, you should capture the response and make sure the **overall status is green**

This also sends `statuses` which shows status of each individual plugin, so if you dont care about certain plugin, you can iterate and check status only for required plugins.

[image: response status]

Comment: This made the trick for me. After sending a request to `http://localhost:5601/api/status` I parsed and checked overall state until it is 'green'.  (I also use data sweet plugin but it does not show up in statuses array even though I installed it following Kibana instructuons.)